# Site home page completely messed up?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, master-page

I was trying to add a dropdown for top menu bar in a SharePoint 2013 site. I opened the site in SPD 2013 and followed the instructions as mentioned in [How to create drop-down menu in the SharePoint Foundation subsite via SharePoint Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55ldj.png).

Home Page got completely messed up. **Sub-sites looks perfect**. **only root site home page got messed up**

Now it looks like below screen shot.

[image]

I set `v4.master` to default page which is the original copy. Still I see the same.

Comment: Please have a look this link:http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2013/05/mega-menu-for-sharepoint-part-1/

Comment: You should be using Seattle.master as it is 2013 site